# default deployment Grails3 and Angular profile

Tags: angular, gradle, war, grails3.2.0

Is there a best way to deploy the Grails3 war when using the Angular (which is in fact Angular2) profile?  I am using Grails 3.2.9.   It runs fine in development mode.   Was hoping for a one-step gradle build command to create a single combined war file.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I was given after posting it as an issue was this:

http://guides.grails.org/angular2-combined/guide/index.html

Of course, you can just run the static html off of nginx/apache and the grails as a REST server off of anything else.